# Test whether login user has rights for installing COA or not

Tags: security, odoo, access-rights

I want to test whether login user has rights for installing COA or not?

I tried to check with group "Financial Manager". Now the problem is users other than Admin can't install COA without "Financial Manager" rights so it works while admin can install it without "Financial Manager" rights.

So how can I test it whether user has rights for installing COA or not.

Thanx and Regards,

Answer (score 0):

Any kind of installation in OpenERP is not possible without "administration" rights. SO if user doesn't have administration rights then CoA installation will not be possible.